# Find the value of a line

Tags: c++

So I am trying to make a program in C++ that finds the line of a word from a text file and displays the line number.
I don't have any errors while compiling, but the line value is always a weird number like 1972007907.

The code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main()
{

std::ifstream readFile ("example.txt");





if( readFile.is_open() )
{
    int line;
    std::cout << "Write the word you're searching for\n" ;
    std::string word ;
    std::cin >> word ;



    std::string candidate ;
    while( readFile >> candidate )
    {
        line++;

    }

    std::cout << "The word " << word << " has been found " << " on line " <<line<<"\n";
}

else
{
    std::cout << "Error! File not found!\n" ;
    return 1 ;
}
}
```

Comment: `int line = 0;` You forgot to initialize it. But there are other issues as well.

Comment: The code doesn't do what you claim it is trying to do.

Comment: Could you point out what the issues are and maybe how can i solve them?

Comment: Hmm the main problem is that you are not checking if the word is present in the line. You are just incrementing the line count and blindly printing that the word is present on the last line assuming line is initialized to 0.

Comment: Moreover line count will not be equal to the number of lines in the file. It will be equal to the number of words in the file. Check cppreference for getline() function which is what you want to use if you want to read a line and not whitespace separated words

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of your problem is that your line counter is reading the total number of lines in the file regardless of whether you find the line your are looking for.
You need to add a condition in the while loop that breaks out of the loop once the word is encountered.  The pseudocode would be as follows:

while(readline from file)
        if(word found in readline)
           exit loop
        increment line
   end while loop

You would need to change your while loop to read a line:

```
while(std::getline(readFile, candidate)){
    // rest of your logic goes here
}
```